# What is the error made in this strategy for solving linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The solution to the system $4y=3x+7$ and $9x+4y-139=0$ is shown below.

[image]

I solved for the solution and found that the answer is correct, and is $(11, 10)$. But, what is the mistake that is made here? I'm assuming the strategy is incorrect because it does not look like it would work with different situations involving systems.

Comment: It's correct and that's how they are solved, there are quicker method though

Comment: So essentially she just simplified both equations, and then solved?

Comment: Yes, she just subsituted and rearranged to get the solution that's how it's done

Answer (score 0):

As Oussama mentioned, there is an easier way to look at this. Write the first equation as:
$$3x-4y=-7,$$
and the second equation as:
$$9x+4y=139.$$
Then, we have:
\begin{align}
9x+4y &= 139\\
3x-4y &= -7.
\end{align}
Add the two equations together to get:
\begin{align}
9x+4y &= 139\\
3x-4y &= -7\\
\hline \\
12x&= 132.
\end{align}
Notice that this method didn't require as many algebraic manipulations. Now, solve for $y$ just as before and you are done.